# Remove Binary from IDA Database

Tags: ida, disassembly, binary-analysis

I saw the `File -> Load File -> Additional Binary File` option and tried it out. Now I want my original IDA database back (with just one binary), but can't afford to lose the comments I have saved in it.

Is it possible to remove a binary after importing it?

Comment: Did you save the database?

Comment: Yep, I saved it after doing so, however, otherwise I would have lost comments.

Comment: You can use/write a plugin that exports/imports comments. Here is a plugin I wrote with some importing/exporting functionality you can use for inspiration: https://github.com/x64dbg/x64dbgida/blob/master/x64dbgida.py just reopen the file and create a new database and then import comments/labels you exported from your old database.

Comment: @mrexodia Make that an answer, it sounds like the easiest way to do what I want! Especially if it is actually impossible to unexport/remove the second binary.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, the built-in function of saving data for export as an IDC script will help you. Try File -> Produce File -> Dump database to IDC script, then create new database and just run IDC script.

Comment: He'll need to clean all IDC instructions related to the additionally loaded binary, though.